# Characterizing groups with linear subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Is there a simple characterization for a group $G$ satisfying
$$(\forall H,K\le G)(H\subseteq K\text{ or } K\subseteq H)$$

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quasicyclic_group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: First, Assume that  $x\in G$ with infinite order. Compare $x^p$ and $x^q$ where $p,q$ are distinct prime numbers. Now Suppose that $G$ is torsion. Compare elements with order $p$ and $q$ where $p,q$ are distinct prime numbers.

In next step. you should show that $G$ is abelian group.

Finally, you should got $G=\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ where $n\in \mathbb N\cup \{\infty\}$

Comment: well if $G$ is not torsion-free it is a p-group. what if it is torsion-free?

Comment: @user138171 $G$ cannot contain an element with infinite order.